# Causing an artificial infinite deadlock on MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

Is there a way of causing an artificial infinite deadlock on MSSQL? I need to cause a deadlock so I can test out some stored procedure to automatically remove the deadlock. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Brendan McCaffrey is right that, under normal circumstances, SQL Server will identify and resolve deadlocks automatically.

There are sometimes bugs that result in *undetected* deadlocks.  The conventional advice on dealing with those would be to apply available updates to SQL Server, and if the problem persists to open a ticket with Microsoft about it.

If you really have problems with undetected (infinite) deadlocks in your environment, and need a way to create the situation so you can test your programmatic approach to killing them, Joe Obbish has a good way of creating one here:

[Unkillable Sessions and Undetected Deadlocks](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/unkillable-sessions-and-undetected-deadlocks/)

A summary of that approach is to run a normal query that will take and hold some locks, and then run an `OPENROWSET` query in the same session that requests locks on the same object(s).  This results in a strange circular dependency that won't resolve on its own, and SQL Server doesn't detect as a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

Deadlocks, by nature, are infinite. A deadlock occurs when two transactions are blocking each other. Neither transaction can move forward until the other transaction releases its lock. However, with each one waiting on the other, neither transaction will ever release its lock.

However, SQL Server checks for deadlocks every 5 seconds, and chooses a victim. Thus, I'm not sure you'd really need to build a process to do something SQL Server already does.

The better way to handle deadlocks is to monitor for them. If you notice a high number of them, go to your application team and ask if they are gracefully handling a deadlock situation when executing transactions in the database. It's possible they are, and that they don't really care if the deadlocks are happening.

In short, if a deadlock is happening, a transaction is being aborted to allow the remaining transaction to continue. If the application is not handling them, then someone is probably complaining somewhere about them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do this.

Brent Ozar created a guide called [Deadlocks: let’s do one, understand it, and fix it.](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/deadlocks/).

And there is also a [video](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/05/free-video-deadlocks-lets-do-one-understand-it-and-fix-it/).

Comment: If you reread the OP, they're asking to create an infinite deadlock. I.E., one that SQL Server will not resolve within 5 seconds. Creating a random deadlock is easy.

Comment: but you said that "Deadlocks, by nature, are infinite.". If you look at minute 11 in Brent's video you will see that SQL Server Engine is not going to resolve that in 5 seconds. I think the example and the code I provided are good. What do you think?

Comment: Right, "by nature". That is why SQL Server already has a built in way to handle them.  The bigger point of the OP, is that they want to create one, so they can write a way to kill one. But SQL already does this. If you go back to minute 11 in Brent O.'s video and watch closely, you'll see he created a 'blocking' situation at that moment, not a deadlock. Blocking, unlike deadlocking, will continue indefinitely in SQL Server, until the lead blocker completes on its own, or is killed.